# SpringArgumentResolver is preventing other request parameters which is coming either from request body or request param. any solution?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, arguments, java-ee-6

I am using spring argument resolver by implementing HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. It is working fine and setting parameters which is coming from header, but it's preventing parameter which came from request param/path variable or request body.
my code has requirement of both like some params are coming from header while other from request body or path. below is my code,

config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringWebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new SpringArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```

resolver class:

```
    public final class SpringArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return CommonHeader.class.isAssignableFrom(parameter.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

        CommonHeader commonHeader = BeanUtils.instantiateClass(parameter.getParameterType(), CommonHeader.class);

         String request_id = webRequest.getHeader("request_id");

         if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(request_id)) {
            commonHeader.setRequest_id(request_id);
        }
      return commonHeader;
}
```

}

commonHeader class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CommonHeader {

    private String request_id;
    private String ip_address;
}
```

request class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class GetDataRequest extends CommonHeader {

    private String user_id;
    private String userName;
}
```

controller method:

```
@GetMapping("user_data")
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<JsonNode>> getUserData(GetDataRequest getDataRequest) {
          DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<JsonNode>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
         // some logic 
       return deferredResult;
    }
```

this code is working, not it is either setting parameters which is coming in header, or only parameters which comes in as request params. some problem with argument resolver. don't know what. because I have this type of argument resolver working fine with spring webflux project. can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: You have provided your own creation mechanism so Spring will backoff, your `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` is in charge now no others will be called. It isn't a multistep process!. If you want that you will need to  implement binding yourself (and/or marshalling) as you are in control. Finally you are using Spring BOot so remove the `@EnableWebMvc` that will actually disable auto configuration (not that it will solve your issue but it isn't needed).

Comment: but as I described my requirement as i need both argumentSolver setting header parameters and also request class params. this type of code working with webflux demo code. can you please me if you can,  https://github.com/martinnemec3/spring-argument-resolver-demo

Comment: It doesn't work their either. It works there for only a request body due to the extension of the `AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver`. It won't work for binding request parameters. So again it will not work unless you implement your own databinding/serialization in your resolver as well.

Comment: do you mean I have to bind all the request params. in resolver like i did for header param? or because request will be different for different request and I did this for all request. can I automate that binding in like all request classes with diff. params ? is that possible by using anything like AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver

Comment: I strongly suggest you start first understanding the technologies you are using. Spring will use either a `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` (for binding) or a `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` (for de-serializing) if you want yours to do both you will need to implement the logic of these 2 into your own processor.

Comment: I will try these. Thanks for your help. @M.Deinum